# Is there a way to sharpen low quality images

Tags: adobe-photoshop, compression, image-editing

I have a lot of images for a project that are not really sharp and crisp. I think these were old images that were resized a lot etc.

This is because I am working on a website for a client and she does not have the high quality pictures anymore, the pictures I have to work with are somewhat pixelated.

Here's an example of one I think could be better:

[image]

Now as you can see the parts around the text 'Azule' is not so sharp. Is there a way to sharpen this.

Now I have another one, and I think there is no hope for this one.

[image]

Is there any hope for the picture above to make it sharp again, I highly doubt it.

Comment: Not really. You can't gain image quality out of nothing. There are probably ways to work around this, though, so I won't give an actual answer.

Comment: Do you have the right to use these pictures? If so I'd really try to find the originals (I know you say you can't).

Comment: Ok I will let her try and find the originals trough the company. But this is a problem I am facing in a lot of other projects, even my own where I lost the originals. So thats why I asked.

Comment: The second is beyond repair anyway. The first one may be repaired with a little help of the answer of Andy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If my eyes don't deceive me, what you're seeing around Azule is a compression artefact - ie it comes from taking an original high quality image, and compressing it heavily. You can try to minimise the effects of this, but you really want the originals wherever possible. Here's a (random!) link about reducing compression artefacts using Photoshop. Google for more. (And always keep a copy of your pictures that doesn't use lossy compression.)

EDIT: Forgot the link - http://graphicssoft.about.com/od/photoshop/ss/cs2reducenoise.htm

Comment: yes that is the problem. The person I am working does not have the original images anymore. These are the only ones I am stuck with.

Comment: I don't think you'll find an amazing _It just works_ method then. You can try noise reduction filters, manual touch up, and lots of patience :) Sorry there's nothing better...

Comment: And make sure you keep a copy of all your current JPGs, and copies of all your retouched versions in a lossless format like TIFF.

Comment: +1 the typical way to reduce this is with a combination re-touching the images where the artefacts are most prominent and blurring the image to soften the effects of pixellation; in a raster image editor (Photoshop GIMP). The #1 rule of photo editing is, always save the highest quality version because quality lost is quality that can't be re-gained.

Answer (score 0):

The labels seem to be the main issue where the pixelation is noticeable.  If you have one of those labels on hand, you could make a high res scan of it and photoshop it onto the bottles.  Getting the curving and shading right might be hard for someone new to photoshop, but would be pretty quick and easy for someone with a few years of experience for it, so it might be relatively cheap to pay someone (probably wouldn't be a huge project for them).  This should be significantly cheaper than hiring someone to retake photos.

Answer (score 0):

You can use tools like Lightroom or DXO Optics Pro.

In DXO OP there is a thing called mikro sharpening which can help - but in the end it will be better to make new images and let your customer learn the lesson to keep originals.

Micro Sharpening works best with raw images and tries to interpolate fine structures. Normal sharpening often only makes a sort of edge sharpening. For example I use images with insects or spiders. With normal sharpening you get more crisp but e.g. sharp legs. With micro sharpening you sometimes get the small hairs of the legs, even if you can't see them in the original image. In DXO it is a slider called micro sharpening. This won't work with very low resolution images well and requires a minimum size of image.